# Sorting a dictionary by values

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a dictionary 'a' if:

```
a = {6:32 , 1:15 , 3:45 , 2:12 , 5:46, 4:99}
```

I want to sort this dict by values with respect to its keys, such as this:

```
a = {2:12 , 1:15 , 6:32 , 3:45 , 5:46 , 4:99}
```

I wanted to know if it's possible without importing any modules.

Thanks

Comment: Did you Google your question title?

Comment: Do you just want to display it sorted, do you want to convert it into an `OrderedDict`, or do you want to rely on the Python 3.6 implementation detail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A dictionary has no sort order.  But you can sort the keys and retrieve them in order.  [For example:](http://rextester.com/EPPY39192)

```
for k in sorted(a, key=lambda k: a[k]):
    print k, a[k]
```

The "key" `lambda` function specifies by which value to sort.  In the example it sorts by the key's value in the dictionary.

Comment: It sorts perfectly. As I wanted it to be in a dictionary, I edited the body of the loop as:
a_sortedAsc = {}
for k in sorted(a, key = lambda k: a[k]):
    a_sortedAsc.update({k: a[k]})

Comment: Please don't provide answer to a question that obviously has dupes and considering the linked dupe has 46 answers. Also there was [no attempt from OP whatsoever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353940/why-would-a-question-thats-normally-too-broad-in-any-other-language-be-okay-i).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The question you marked as "duplicate source" does indeed have 46 contradicting and convoluted answers.  One of the worst SO pages to land on from Google.

Comment: How did your answer help? How is this better than using simple `dict.get`? If you see their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658112/sorting-a-dictionary-by-values/45658150?noredirect=1#comment78274924_45658150), they are still appending keys back to a normal dict. Means they learned nothing. :-(

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: well, my answer may not be the best, but why not try? One day there will hopefully be a better Q&A that you land on if you Google "python sort dictionary by value".